# Defining a WebAPI route without the /api/{controller} prefix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to process requests in format without the /api/{Controller} prefix (e.g. *www.myapp.com/download/image1.jpg*) by a WebAPI controller method. Is it even possible or do I need do switch to MVC controller? I Defined the following route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Check",
                routeTemplate: "download",
                defaults: new { controller = "Download", action = "CheckAccess" });
```

but unfortunately it is not working, the controller doesn't even gets created (I have traces in the constructor)

Comment: Try attribute routing  ( only available in web api 2)

Comment: That worked! IF you change your comment to an answer, I can confirm it. The other solution is to add a delegate handler, this can be used for routes of any kind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try attribute routing ( only available in web api 2)

Comment: Attribute routing is available on WebApi v1 through NuGet

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Check", 
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}");
            defaults: new { controller = "Download", action = "CheckAccess" });
```